# zepto.js vs xuijs for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, zepto, xui

I'm developing with PhoneGap for a month already. In my first app, I used JQuery and the results were horrible. I learned about zepto.js and xuijs being two of the most recommended libraries for cross-platform development. What do you think of these two? which one should I use? Any other things to consider? Any other tips to improve the performance of my apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I t depends on the App, mainly. If it's going to be using animation, I highly reccomend Zepto, as it makes that really easy. If you're going to be developing one using multiple views, I would reccomend xuijs, or [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch). It really depends on what you're going to be doing with it.